# Standardising get_success_url

Tags: python, django, django-models, get, django-views

For my classes `PostCreateView` and `PostUpdateView` I have the same `get_success_url`. Is there a way of standardising your `get_success_url`, I want to avoid writing the code twice?

```
def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])
```

I was working through a tutorial. A limitation of the tutorial though was you were only shown how to load posts by using the posts primary key (https://rossdjangoawesomeapp2.herokuapp.com/post/6/). I modified the code in the tutorial so you could access posts using their title (https://rossdjangoawesomeapp2.herokuapp.com/post/another-test-please-let-it-work/). Which has resulted in me having duplicate code.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
 class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        # will save the form and redirect to the success_url
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For my classes `PostCreateView` and `PostUpdateView` I have the same `get_success_url`. Is there a way of standardising your `get_success_url`, I want to avoid writing the code twice?

**Yes**, not writing it at all. If you do not specify a `get_success_url`, or `success_url`, Django will take the `get_absolute_url` of the *object* (so here the `Post` object). Hence if you do not specify it, then it will already redirect to the correct url, this is specified in the documentation for the [**`get_success_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url):

> Determine the URL to redirect to when the form is successfully validated. Returns `django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url` if it is provided; otherwise, attempts to **use the `get_absolute_url()` of the object**.

So we can remove the `get_success_url` methods:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    # no get_success_url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )

    # no get_success_url
```

Comment: That code is working perfectly. But I don't really understand it. Because one user can write many posts. And it doesn't appear as if we are pasting a PK or title to def get_queryset.

Comment: @RossSymonds: it does, Django's `SingleObjectMixin` (mixins that are for example in `UpdateVIew` and `DetailView`) implement logic in the `get_object` that checks if there is a `pk` or a `slug` in the urls, and filter on the pk/slug automatically.